# What happends to the memory contents at argv[1] after the line of code?

Tags: c++, c++17

What happends to the memory contents at `argv[1]` after the line of code?

```
strcpy(card_name, argv[1]);
```

Comment: Nothing. Why, does it seems that something is happening to it in your program? Could you try to create a [mcve] to show us? And please show us the arguments to the program, as well as the expected and actual output of the shown example program. Also please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: thanks for the help, but this was a theoretical question given to me(so no other code than this) and i did not know the answer to it. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: when in doubt RTFM (read the fine manual). Asking a question here for each function you need to look up will be cumbersome.

Comment: I suggest you bookmark [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing will happen due to `strcpy()` call.**

The syntax of the strcpy() function is:

```
char* strcpy (char* destination, const char* source);
```

Notice that `source` is preceded by the `const` modifier because `strcpy()` function is not allowed to **change** the `source` string.

Comment: Clear explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in particular. It depends highly on the the program after that line of code.